# If $n$ is a composite integer larger than $8$, then $n \mid(n-3) !$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So far my understanding is that let $n$ be the product of some integer $(a,b,c...)$, and try to prove $a,b,c...$ $\in$  $[1,n-3]$. Then I stuck at here and wonder if I am on the right truck? Could anyone give me some hints? Thank you!

Comment: It’s true for composite $n\geq 6,$ not just $n>8.$ Basically, it is true for any composite $n$ other than $4.$

Comment: Hint:  if $n$ is divisible by something $3$ or greater (what?)  if $n$ is not divisible by something $3$ or greater (what?)  There is one special case to consider.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! I think I figure it out! Thank you!

Comment: @JesseJin If you get a chance, you should type an answer to your question!

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ can be written the product of 2 *distinct* integers $a,b$ neither 1, then if $n$ is at least $8$, then both $a$, $b$ are no larger than $\frac{n}{2} \le n-3$ [why is this] and
$$(n-3)!=1×\cdots × (a-1)a×\cdots ×b×\cdots ×(n-3).$$ As $n=a×b$ it follows then that $n|(n-3)!$.

If $n$ cannot be written $n=ab$ for 2 distinct $a$ and $b$, then as $n$ is composite, it follows that $n=p^2$ for some $p$ satisifying $2<p\le (n-3)/2$ [check this for yourself]. Then as $p$ is no larger than $(n-3)/2$, it follows that $p$ , $2p$ are both no larger than $n-3$, and thus:
$$(n-3)!=1×\cdots ×(p-1)×p×\cdots ×2p× \cdots ×(n-3).$$ As $n|p×2p$ it follows then that $n|(n-3)!$.